# Hosting migration - no email downtime

Tags: domain-name-system, migration, web-hosting

I need to move the current hosting to a new location with interrupting email.
Currently the MX done by a 3rd party hosting company.

- Does not matter if users see old or new site during move.
- Email cannot be interrupted during the move 24/7 business.

The image shows the logic on migration.

[DNS Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsGVx.png)

If you see any flaw, please let me know in detail.

Thank you-

Edit: 
Answer to mythofechelon

Only the web hosting provider is going to change.
Though the current web hosting is providing some DNS, MX records point to it.

Comment: Are you migrating your domain, name servers, mail server, web server, or all?

Comment: When you change MX records it takes some time for all the email servers on the internet to see the change. You can set the DNS TTL to 5 minutes, but not all servers respect thing. Therefore during your migration email can be sent to either server. If you really need to lose absolutely no email the old server will need a way to send email to the new server.

Comment: If you're simply changing the web hosting then you don't need to and shouldn't change the NS records nor the MX records. You should only change the records related to the website.

Answer (score 1):

### Assumption:

- Website ... Shift to the new hosting service provider
- Email ... NOT going to be shifted. Stay the same before/after this change.
- You are using name server services along with web hosting service from FlyWheel, and trying to relocate these services to the new provider. So, your task is basically two, one is to change the name server, and the other is to change the web hosting.

### Suggestion:

1. Duplicate "all" the entries in the current name servers to the new servers.
2. Once all entries are copied, modify name servers in the registrar portal so that it points to the new name servers.(eg. [GoDaddy "Change Name Servers for my domain"](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/change-nameservers-for-my-domains-664))
3. (optional)Change TTL of your web server entries to the shorter value.
4. Change A record of your web servers (from old servers to the new one)

Comment: between options 2 and 3 give enough time for DNS propagation for the name server changes done.